# Analytic function dominated in the boundary is dominated on the domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be analytic functions on an open bounded set $\Omega$ and continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$ and $g$ is never zero in ${\Omega}$

Suppose that $\left|f\right| \leq \left|g\right|$ on the boundary then show that $\left| f \right| \leq \left|g\right|$ on all $\Omega$.

Based on the hypothesis I guess I have to use the maximum principle somehow, but I don't see how.

Comment: Hint: Try look at the ratio of $f$ and $g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\frac{f}{g}$ is continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$ and holomorphic in $\Omega$. Since this is a continuous function on a compact set it follows that $\frac{|f|}{|g|}$ has a maximum in $\overline{\Omega}$. From the maximum modulus principle it follows that the maximum must be achieved on the boundary. But by assumption the maximum of this function on the boundary is at most $1$.